# Whats wrong with my flask Login/Signup function?

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, flask

I have a problem with my login/signup function. My login function is

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import request
import os
import json

app = Flask('app')

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def intro():
    return render_template("home.html")

@app.route('/game', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def game():
    return render_template("game.html")
 
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    path = 'users'
    uname = ""
    password = ""
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uname = request.form['email']
        password = request.form['psw']
    with open(os.path.join(path, "users.json"), 'r') as myfile:
        data = myfile.read()
    try:
#TypeError: string indices must be integers |/_
        if data['username'] == uname:
            try:
                if data['password'] == password:
                    return render_template("game.html")
                else:
                    return "wrong password"
            except TypeError:
                print("TypeError2")
        else:
            return f"{uname}"
            return "wrong username"
    except TypeError:
             print("TypeError")
    
    return render_template("login.html")

@app.route('/signup', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():
    uname = ""
    password = ""
    path = 'users'


    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)

    else:
        pass


    if request.method == 'POST':
        uname = request.form['email']
        password = request.form['psw']

        with open(os.path.join(path, "users.json"), 'r') as myfile:
            data = myfile.read()
            obj = json.loads(data)

            data = {}
            data["username"] = uname
            data["password"] = password
            

            obj.append(data)

        with open(os.path.join(path, "users.json"), "w") as outfile:
            json.dump(obj, outfile) 
    
            data["password"] = password

            obj.append(data)

        with open(os.path.join(path, "users.json"), "w") as outfile:
            json.dump(obj, outfile) 
    
        return render_template("game.html")

    return render_template("signup.html")
    

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

Does this mean my username has to be numbers only? And how can I change this?

I get my data from a .json file, then read/write it. I am suspecting I should have something instead of an 'if statement', and possibly remove it altogether.

My html code for login.html (my login page) is in a folder called templates. Below is what is inside that file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
form {border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;}

input[type=text], input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.cancelbtn {
  width: auto;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  background-color: #f44336;
}

.imgcontainer {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
}

img.avatar {
  width: 40%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.container {
  padding: 16px;
}

span.psw {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 16px;
}

/* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  span.psw {
     display: block;
     float: none;
  }
  .cancelbtn {
     width: 100%;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<center><h1>Login</h1></center>

<form action="game" method="POST">
  <div class="imgcontainer">
    <img src="an image with way to many characters to post" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>

    <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

    <button type="submit">Login</button>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
    </label>
  </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

My html code for signup.html (my signup page) is in a folder called templates. Below is what is inside that file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Add padding to containers */
.container {
  padding: 16px;
  background-color: white;
}

/* Full-width input fields */
input[type=text], input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

input[type=text]:focus, input[type=password]:focus {
  background-color: #ddd;
  outline: none;
}

/* Overwrite default styles of hr */
hr {
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

/* Set a style for the submit button */
.registerbtn {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.registerbtn:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

/* Add a blue text color to links */
a {
  color: dodgerblue;
  decoration: none
}

/* Set a grey background color and center the text of the "sign in" section */
.signin {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>  
<form method="POST">
  <div class="container">
    <center><h1>Signup</h1></center>
    <hr>

    <label for="email"><b>Email</b></label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" id="email" required>

    <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Numbers Only Password" name="psw" id="psw" required>

    <label for="psw-repeat"><b>Repeat Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password" name="psw-repeat" id="psw-repeat" required>
    <hr>

    <button type="submit" class="registerbtn">Signup</button>
  </div>
  
  <div class="container signin">
    <p>Already have an account? <a href="/login">Login</a>.</p>
  </div>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because the variable `data` is a string, not a dictionary. You need to convert it to a dictionary using Python's `json` library with the `loads` function. Replace the code in the `with open` block with this:

```py
with open(os.path.join(path, "users.json"), 'r') as myfile:
        data = json.loads(myfile.read())
```

Then don't forget to import the Json library at the top of the file.

```py
import json
```